# How to install SQL Server support for Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, dbml

I am not able to connect to SQL Server `.dbml` file. When I am trying to connect to SQL Server, it shows a message to "install the missing package". Now, when I am installing that missing plug-in, it just shows the progress bar and at last shows "Installation completed". But again when I try to connect, it shows the above error message.

Can anyone please help me to install it manually?

Step 1:

[image]

Step 2:

[image]

Step 3:

[image]

Comment: Try running visual studio `as admin` and then install it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, let me try and inform you

Comment: @Pritam not working

Answer (score 0):

Search for and install the latest version of SSDT (Sql Server Data Tools).

Answer (score 0):

I install Visual Studio (community edition) quite often and this happened to one of the PCs I develop on.

Uninstalling/Re-installing Visual Studio is what make this work.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Visual Studio 2017, the functionality of creating Database Projects has been integrated into the Visual Studio installation. There is no need to install the SSDT standalone installer for the core SSDT experience. To create Integration Services/Analysis Services/Reporting Services projects you still need the SSDT standalone installer.

For Database Projects, install the **Data Storage and Processing workload** for Visual Studio
For Analysis Services, Integration Services or Reporting Services projects, download and install SQL Server Data Tools